# C++ Eclipse: Build a MacOSX App under Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, macos, gcc

I have a C++ command line project using Eclipse under fedora
(Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)).
Now i want to port this to the Mac.
To my surprise in the project settings of eclipse, in the list of available tool chains i found the entry "MacOSX GCC":

[image]

which contains a MacOS X C++ Linker. So i switched the used toolchain to this and rebuilt. The resulting file can still be executed under linux but its not executable when moved to a mac. It differs though slightly in size from the version built with the Linux GCC toolchain, but sill it is a linux, not a mac executable.

Question:

- Can the MacOS X toolchain be used anyhow in the linux environment or
  is this rather a bug?
- If yes: What do i have to do, to build a MacOS X application under linux?

Comment: That's not what you want. You want to install the proper toolchain first: This is the only toolchain I know of, which was maintained until about a year ago. (https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross) You might be out of luck there. May I add that Apple are assholes. They are like Microsoft in the 80s and 90s. In 10 years, when the new kid on the block puts them in the misery Microsoft is in now, they will start doing open source again.

Comment: So what is the toolchain i used good for? Does it have any use?

Comment: No use at all. Don't ask me why it's there. I am no eclipse expert. I can tell you for sure however, that you need a toolchain that eclipse can use. What you want is darwin 64 bit binaries. You will not be able to build those anymore under Linux as it seems.